# grid-template-columns for IE11?

Tags: html, css

So I have this website that runs fine on chrome, but not on IE11. I checked which CSS he's not receiving in IE11 and I see that once I turn off the: `grid-template-columns` in my chrome website, it does the same as in IE11. It doesn't put the elements next to eachother anymore because the width on the columns is set on 100% from an external file. I guess that could be changed but I'm wondering if there's a way I could get this behaviour to work in IE11? The code is:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);`

I have found that it indeed is not supported by IE11:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 -ms-grid-columns: ( 1fr 1em )[3];
```

or

```
-ms-grid-columns:1fr 1em 1fr 1em 1fr;
```

and for each grid items

```
-ms-grid-column:1;  -ms-grid-column:3; -ms-grid-column:5;
```